# How to show convexity of a ball in metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a normed linear space, then how to show any ball $B(x,r)$ is convex?
I know that if $x,y\in A\subset V$ then $[x,y]\subset A$, where $A$ is a convex subset of vector space $V$ and $[x,y]=\{(1-t)x+ty\mid 0\leq t \leq 1\}$. Please give me some hint.

I tried the following:

**Claim.** $[a,b] \subset B(x,r)$
Let $a,b \in B(x,r).$ Then I get $\|x-a\|<r$ and $\|x-b\|<r$.

Is it right?

Comment: Hint: Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Do you mean "if $x,y\in A\subset V$, then $[x,y]\subset A$ where $A$ is a convex  subset of $V$"?

Comment: @KubaHelsztyński yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $a,b \in B(x,r)$. Then $\|a-x\| < r$, and similarly for $b$. You want to show that for any $t \in [0,1]$, $ta+(1-t)b \in B(x,r)$. To do this we must show that $\|ta+(1-t)b-x\| < r$.

Using the triangle inequality we have:
$$\|ta+(1-t)b-x\| = \|t(a-x)+(1-t)(b-x)\| \leq t \|a-x\|+(1-t) \|b-x\| $$
$$< t r +(1-t)r = r,$$
hence $ta+(1-t)b \in B(x,r)$.

Comment: why u r taking b=b-x?

Comment: It a was a cut & paste induced typo.! Thanks for catching it.

Comment: I want to understand please tell me.  in the first step why u r taking b=b-x?

Comment: Can you explain where I am taking $b=b-x$ please? I had a typo. earlier, but now I don't know what you are referring to. Remember, $x=t x + (1-t)x$, and $t\geq0, 1-t \geq 0$.

Comment: $ta+(1-t)b-x  = ta + (1-t) b -tx -(1-t)x = t(x-a)+(1-t) (b-x)$.

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi $x$ was subtracted in first expression, because you want to show that distance between points $ta+(1-t)b$ and $x$ is less than $r$. That was **not** assuming $b=b-x$, but artifical $+tx-tx$ in order to reformulate $\|ta+(1-t)b-x\|$ in a convenient way.

Comment: You want to show $[a,b] \subset B(x,r)$ A typical point of $[a,b]$ is $ta+(1-t)b$, with $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi 'Cause you want to show that $ta+(1-t)b\in B(x,r)$ so you have to show that $\|ta+(1-t)b-x\|$ is less that $r.$

Comment: @KubaHelsztyński i know at last we have to show ta+(1-t)b is less then r but in this case why we r take b-x in place of b

Comment: @KubaHelsztyński ok i understand.thank you somuch.your comment is great so i understand

Comment: @KubaHelsztyński Thank you for your elaborations.

Answer (score 3):

Since convexity is translation invariant, it is sufficient to show that $B(\mathbf{0},r)$ is convex.

In order to do that, take arbitary points $a,b\in B(\mathbf{0},r).$ We will show that any convex combination of $a$ and $b$, namely $ta+(1-t)b$, belongs to $B(\mathbf{0},r).$ In order to do that, fix $t\in [0,1]$ and note that $$\|ta+(1-t)b\|\stackrel{\triangle}{\le}\|ta\|+\|(1-t)b\|\stackrel{\text{homogeneity}}{=}t\|a\|+(1-t)\|b\|<tr+(1-t)r=r.$$
Thus $ta+(1-t)b\in B(\mathbf{0},r)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

In other words, given any points $a,b$ from the ball one has $[a,b]\subset B(\mathbf{0},r)$, which proves desired convexity.

Answer (score 2):

You have listed the immediate consequences of $a,b \in B(x,r)$. Now you want to show that $[a,b] \subset B(x,r)$. You are already given in the statement of the question that an arbitrary point on the line segment $[a,b]$ can be expressed as $(1-t)a + tb; 0\leq t \leq 1$. One way to proceed is to show that $(1-t)a + tb \in B(x,r)$ for any $0\leq t \leq 1$.

You could start with a specific example for $t$, say $t=1/2$. Then write out what it would mean for $\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b \in B(x,r)$. See at that point if you can get the triangle inequality to work out for you given what you already know.

If you can get the proof to work out for $t=1/2$ then you should be able to write out the proof for any $t$ where $0\leq t \leq 1$. Hope this helps.